# Display string in xml format in browser either using view or controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a string in my model.The string is actually XML content. I have a link on my page, when clicked it opens a new tab and displays the text as XML.

The result should be the same as when I right click on an xml file and open with Internet Explorer. The difference is that this is no file, its text that I need to display as XML in a new tab.

Anyone have an idea how to achieve this without creating a file and without giving a path to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a controller that will serve this XML and set the proper content type header:

```
public class MyXMLController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyModel model = GetModelFromSomewhere(...);
        return Content(model.StringPropertyContainingXML, "text/xml");
    }
}
```

now all that's left is to write an `anchor` link pointing to `/myxml/index`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click to open XML", "index", "myxml", null, new { _target = "blank" })
```

Comment: Its actualy on grid cell click and im passing the event.args.value as the data through ajax call to the controller....will this still work